# Failed at step EXEC spawning

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ubuntu

I did everythin' like in Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing.nix-services.system-d) to deploy my app on AWS. But got an error:

```
 deploy-demo.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/deploy-demo/deploy-demo.jar: Exec format error
Sep 07 21:22:10 ip-172-31-45-166 systemd[1]: deploy-demo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
```

My deploy-demo.service file located in /etc/systemd/system/deploy-demo.service with settings:

```
[Unit]
Description=deploy-demo
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=gitlab-runner
ExecStart=/opt/deploy-demo/deploy-demo.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`deploy-demo.jar` and `deploy-demo.conf` located in `/opt/deploy-demo/`

deploy-demo.conf file contains

```
RUN_ARGS="--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://here_is_should_be_my_host:5432/helpfast --spring.datasource.username=postgres --spring.datasource.password=adminadmin"
```

All permissions seems to me correct:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Sep  7 21:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root              4096 Sep  7 20:31 ../
-r-------- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner      200 Sep  7 21:21 deploy-demo.conf
-r-x------ 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 42645024 Sep  7 20:31 deploy-demo.jar*
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: It seems your JAR file can't be executed straight away. Try executing it via a shell by changing the start unit line to: `ExecStart=/bin/sh /opt/deploy-demo/deploy-demo.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed two rows in **deploy-demo.service** and the problem has gone.

```
[Service]

WorkingDirectory=/opt/deploy-demo/

ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar deploy-demo.jar

SuccessExitStatus=143
```